# SQL add where clause to query

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I have a SQL query which joins two table and Returns a result that works good so far. It looks like this:

```
Select * 
From program_recipes ptr 
Left Join recipes r On ptr.recipe_id = r.id 
Where ptr.program_type_id In (2) 
  And r.available = 1
```

Now I want to add a where clauses which check is the title contains a word. I tried this so far but I got a syntax error:

```
Select * 
From program_recipes ptr 
Left Join recipes r On ptr.recipe_id = r.id 
Where ptr.program_type_id In (2) 
  And r.available = 1 
   Or Where r.title LIKE '%word%'
   Or Where r.title LIKE '%word%'
```

Comment: ommit where after or

Comment: no need for the extra `or`s there. And make sure you understand the logical precedence of `and`s and `or`s

Comment: requirements are not clear, no sample data, so i'll pass on this one. goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra where commands and add ()

```
Select * 
From program_recipes ptr 
Left Join recipes r On ptr.recipe_id = r.id 
Where ptr.program_type_id In (2) 
  And (r.available = 1 
   Or   r.title LIKE '%word%'
   Or   r.title LIKE '%word%')
```

Comment: As already commented the second or is semantically unnecessary

Comment: yes using %word% will return anything that has word in it- like abcwordxyz for instance

Comment: @DanielMarcus sry maybe I expressed myself wrong, I am trying to add the or Statement if this where clauses: `Where ptr.program_type_id In (2) ` is wrong so to say. So `Where ptr.program_type_id In (2) ` is not a must have condition

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat the `WHERE`, just need it only once. And please review the precedence between the logical operators `AND` and `OR` to match your needs (add parenthesis if needed).

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    program_recipes ptr 
    Left Join recipes r On ptr.recipe_id = r.id 
Where 
    r.available = 1 AND
    (
        ptr.program_type_id In (2) OR
        r.title LIKE '%word%'
    )
```